# How to pass and consume web api server address for Android and IOS that will differ for all 3 environments Debug, QA, Prod?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I want to make a Cordova based application that will consume data from a web API.
The web API part will be running on 3 different URLs: example.local, example.qa and example.com.

How should I pass and consume web api server address for Android and IOS that will differ for all 3 environments Debug, QA, Prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't want to modify the original build scripts I've solved the problem a bit different than @pauloya. So here is what I did:

1. I've added a Dummy C# Console project to the solution
2. Defined new build configurations for the solution (in my case Beta and QA)
3. Set the build options for all projects as follows (make sure to check the build checkbox for the Dummy project):

   ```
       TestCordovaApp: Debug        | Dummy: Debug
       TestCordovaApp: Debug        | Dummy: Beta
       TestCordovaApp: Debug        | Dummy: QA
       TestCordovaApp: Release      | Dummy: Release    
       TestCordovaApp: Distribution | Dummy: Distribution
   ```
4. Added configuration file for each environment to the Dummy project
5. Manually edited the Dummy.csproj to perform it's magic after-build like so

   ```
       <Target Name="AfterBuild">
           <!-- Environments.plist -->
           <Copy Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)configurations\ios\Environments.$(ConfigurationName).plist')" SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)configurations\ios\Environments.$(ConfigurationName).plist" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\TestCordovaApp\plugins\TestPlugin\src\ios\config\Environments.plist" />
           <!-- TestConfig.xml -->
           <Copy Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)configurations\android\TestConfig.$(ConfigurationName).xml')" SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)configurations\android\TestConfig.$(ConfigurationName).xml" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\TestCordovaApp\plugins\TestPlugin\src\android\config\TestConfig.xml" />
       </Target>
   ```
6. Added a reference to the Dummy project from TestCordovaApp (just ignore the error that the reference type is not supported by this type of project)

NOTE: A rebuild is required each time you want to change the build configuration, but with CTP3 rebuild is required for almost every edit one make to the app, so this should not be an issue.

For consuming the values in Android assuming one have a resource file with strings could be achieved with helper method like this:

```
        private String GetStringResource(String resourceKey)
        {
            String packageName = cordova.getActivity().getPackageName();
            int resourceId = cordova.getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(resourceKey, "string", packageName);
            return cordova.getActivity().getString(resourceId);
        }
```

For consuming the values from iOS I've used the code from this link:[https://gist.github.com/besi/2782045]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using a Pre-build event using the $(ConfigurationName). Unfortunately it looks like Cordova projects can't have build events.
We added a dummy project to the solution with a post-build event that uses the $(ConfigurationName) to copy one of 3 "config.js" files into the project folder.
You can then rely on the configuration being Debug, Release or Distribution for this. You may need to add custom configurations to be able to have more environments.

Comment: It appears that adding custom configuration(s) is not possible. I'm getting an error: Requested build configuration is not supported. Only debug, release and distribution are supported.

Other than that I've managed to implement following solution for iOS: https://gist.github.com/besi/2782045.

I'm still looking for similar solution for Android, or I will go your solution for "managing" ant.properties files.

Comment: We were able to get custom configurations working, but it took a considerable amount of tweaking with files to get it going. I think we passed that error "Requested build configuration is not supported" by editing the csproj/jsproj file to add the custom configuration...

Comment: Our solution is far from ideal because we still need to rebuild projects individually, rebuilding the solution doesn't seem to trigger all builds, and for iOS we still need to change the configuration to "Distribution" for the cordova project or it won't build at the mac. Very messy, but working somehow...